# how do i display popup when new user signup or login or logout?

Tags: php, popup

is that possible when new user signup or login then display popup on administrator page i have popup code but problem is that how do i display everytime user login or logout it should be display popup on administrator page?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup-window.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup-window.js"></script>

<body onload="popup_window_show('#sample', 
{ pos : 'window-right-bottom', width : '270px' });"> 

<div   class="popup_window_css" id="sample">

<table class="popup_window_css">
<tr class="popup_window_css">
<td class="popup_window_css">

<div   class="popup_window_css_head">
<img src="images/close.gif" alt="" width="9" height="9" />
User Has Been Login</div>

<div   class="popup_window_css_body">
<div style="border: 1px solid #808080; padding: 6px; background: #FFFFFF;">

Lorem ipsum dolor 
</div></div>

</td></tr></table></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make sure that when a user logs in or signs up, in a different table lets say called "notification", the "userId" is written in there. Then every once in a while, maybe every 5 seconds(but I don't suggest doing that) you could query the "notification" table and the if there is something, call some javascript function that you wrote to take the information which some function returns about that userId, and make that pop up with a pop up **simulating** function which is written in javascript perhaps because calling *alert()* too much can cause the browser to start irritating you.

Oh... And don't forget to delete the data in the "notification" table after you retrieve it just to make things easier.

Remember that the user will have to make a request first which can be done using javascript. Then the rest is about what you return using php and mysql.

This isn't the most efficient way but it just gets the work done. After all, you want to see a pop up for every user who logs in meaning it has a few users. If it has a lot, you wouldn't do that.

It requires some coding but not so difficult to implement. Unless you want something efficient, then you better simplify this solution on the drawing board. :-)

Hope it gives you an idea as to how to go about it.

Comment: touch do u have any kind of example like that?

Comment: My network is jamming an giving me a hard time to load this page. So I am unable to confirm this video but I have a feeling it's the right one. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8HoVdenZFM  It is a youtube video. These guys are the best I know and I think this will give you an idea as to how it's done. You'll just have to use a different table. :-) But it will be help full. Watch all of the videos while you at it. I did. :-D

Comment: Oh... And if it answered you question. Don't forget to mark this question as answered. The little tick below the voting arrows.